# Is it possible to record a video while using imageStream for face detection with camera plugin?

Tags: flutter, camera, google-mlkit

Actually i want to detect the facial positions using image streams and also i want to record the whole thing. But i am not able to do so while imagestream is working. Is there any way to do so?
I also tried to make another camera controller but still nothing

```
await _cameraService.startVideoRecording().then((value) {
  setState(() {
    recording = true;
  });
   });
 
_cameraService.cameraController.startImageStream((image) async {});
```

Comment: Are you referring to the camera flutter plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/camera)? If so, try report issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22p%3A+camera%22

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary solution, you can modify the camera plugin in two places

1. Dart side: in `startImageStream()` and `stopImageStream()` method, Delete/comment out the crash code where `isRecordingvideo` is true.
2. Dart side: in `startVideoRecording()` , Delete/comment out the crash code where `isStreamingImages` is true.